# jaxb(jax-ws) soap WSDL - absent parameters in methods

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I made a SOAP application, it has a `@WebService` interface and implementation, and can be launched via publisher class or from Tomcat. Problem is: generated WSDL doesn't contain structures of `<complexType>`, hence no elements inside. This is what I want:

```
<xs:complexType name="customer">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

(well, this is not a method, but methods contain similar stuff in OK wsdl's)
So, I made a helloworld application to try and generate good WSDL; made an entity "Customer", and used `SchemaOutputResolver`, and not `@WebInterface`-implementation-publisher approach to get WSDL above. 
However, when I made for the helloworld web-service(with a single method):

```
    @WebService
public interface CustomerServInterface {
    @WebMethod
    String gimmeCustomer(@WebParam(name = "CustomerY") Customer customer);
}
```

, its implementation:

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "myJaxb.CustomerServInterface")
public class CustomerServImpl implements CustomerServInterface {
    @Override
    public String gimmeCustomer(@WebParam(name = "CustomerQQ") Customer customer) {
        if (customer != null) return "Received!";
        else return "received null";
    }
}
```

, and publisher:

```
public class CustomerServPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");

        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/customer", new CustomerServImpl());
    }
}
```

, and had Customer's class already @XmlRootElement and every its field @XmlElement(which obviously worked before), my WSDL obtained from publisher is again without arguments:

```
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://myJaxb/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/customer?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="gimmeCustomer">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:gimmeCustomer"/>
</message>
<message name="gimmeCustomerResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:gimmeCustomerResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="CustomerServInterface">
<operation name="gimmeCustomer">
<input wsam:Action="http://myJaxb/CustomerServInterface/gimmeCustomerRequest" message="tns:gimmeCustomer"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://myJaxb/CustomerServInterface/gimmeCustomerResponse" message="tns:gimmeCustomerResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="CustomerServImplPortBinding" type="tns:CustomerServInterface">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="gimmeCustomer">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
```

(truncated it a bit for convinience)

Not only method's gimmeCustomer argument(customer or CustomerY or CustomerQQ) absent, but also class Customer at all!
And I absolutely don't get it. Google didn't give much answers either(although I am not alone with this question). I fell like not understanding something quite obvious.

Thanks in advance for useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't get that directly figured out. Instead, I changed style to RPC:

```
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface CustomerServInterface {
```

and that made method parameters appear as arg0, arg1 etc. Then

`String authorize(@WebParam(name = "login") String login) {`

@WebParam before every parameter(in interface class) solved names problem.

However, it was an unwanted change, judging from jax-ws RPC vs Document descriptions from google. Meh.

Now problem is that entity class Customer itself doesn't get mapped to my WSDL, though

```
<message name="gimmeCustomer">
<part name="CustomerY" type="tns:customer"/>
</message>
```

tns here means(presumably) that 'customer' should appear in the same wsdl. But that's another topic.